# AJAX in Sharepoint 2010 Web Parts

Tags: web-part, ajax

I want to use HighCharts in Sharepoint Web Parts. So, I put necessary JS files in 14 hive folder and everything works fine. This is my ScriptLink Tag:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" Name="<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/STYLES/MyWebPart/Highcharts/js/highcharts.js%>" runat="server" />
```

But when I want to use AJAX, there is a problem:

I don't know how can I address the AJAX URL:

```
function requestData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: ' ?? ',
            success: function(point) {
                var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20;
                chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);    
            },
            cache: false
        });
}
```

I have tested this solution without a chance:

```
url: '< % = ResolveUrl("$SPUrl:~SiteCollection/STYLES/MyWebPart/data.json") % >'
```

Even if I use full URL I got Runtime Error with FireBug (Net Tab): (In this situation if I use incorrect URLs I got 404 Not Found Error)

```
url: 'http://sharepoint/_layouts/1033/STYLES/MyWebPart/data.json'
```

At last if I use HighChart URL with "crossDomain: true" nothing happens:

```
url: 'http://www.highcharts.com/studies/live-server-data.php'
```

It seems Web Parts have some problems with AJAX.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Where is your data.json file? Have you tries `jQyery.ajax` instead of `$.ajax`?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I trid. The data.json file is in the "_layouts/1033/STYLES/MyWebPart/" folder where jQuery and HighCharts is there too.

Comment: Then specifying `'/_layouts/1033/STYLES/MyWebPart/data.json'` as url should work. What is fiddler giving you for that?

Comment: Server Error in '/' Application. (Runtime Error) and it says: set <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly"/> in web.config. But I don't have web.config file in WebPart Solution.

Comment: Change the web.config in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS`

Comment: Thank you Per. Now it says: "Parser Error Message: The page must have a <%@ webservice class="MyNamespace.MyClass" ... %> directive." and Line 1: [1333958544000, 16]. (this is my array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to this line:

```
<add name="JSONHandlerFactory" path="*.json" verb="*" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

in the <system.webServer><handlers> section in the standard SharePoint 2010 web.config. SharePoint (well in fact ASP.NET) assumes that any file with the extension .json should be json enabled web services.

So if your `data.json` is just data then you have to give it another extension.

Comment: Thank you Per Very Much. It works now with another extension. So, how can I call a .json file? How can I use this web service? Any references?

Comment: There is one article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45275/Create-a-JSON-WebService-in-ASP-NET-2-0-with-a-jQu)